# Count function and number

Tags: javascript, string, function, count, numbers

Write a function - countNumbers It should accept string with different symbols and return an object which contains counts of each number.

Tip: consider reusing makeNumber function.
My solution is not full, what should i do the next?

```
function countNumbers (string) {
   let numbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     if (!isNaN(parseInt(string[i]))){
         numbers.push([string[i]])
     }
  }
  return numbers.join('');
};

for example: countNumbers('erer384jj4444666888jfd123');
// => {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 5, '6': 3, '8': 4}

countNumbers('jdjjka000466588kkkfs662555');
// => {'0': 3, '2': 1, '4': 1, '5': 4, '6': 4, '8': 2}
```

Comment: The requirements suggest to reuse the `makeNumber()` function; can you share its code too, please?

Comment: ... in any case, `return numbers.join('');` will return a string, not an object

Comment: this code is a makeNumber()

Comment: your function should return an object, not a string or array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an object instead of an array, and check if the property already exists. If it does then add 1, else set it to start with 1.

In your code you return a string with `return numbers.join('');` but in this case your can return the object instead.

```js
function countNumbers(string) {
  let numbers = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let val = string[i];
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(val))) {
      val in numbers ? numbers[val]++ : numbers[val] = 1;
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}

console.log(countNumbers('erer384jj4444666888jfd123'));
console.log(countNumbers('jdjjka000466588kkkfs662555'));
```

Or as pointed out by @[secan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14201528/secan) as an alternative solution you can use a pattern `[0-9]` with the global flag `/g` to get the digits from the string.

```js
const countNumbers = str => {
  const counterObj = {};
  str.match(/[0-9]/g).forEach(
    s => counterObj.hasOwnProperty(s) ? counterObj[s] += 1 : counterObj[s] = 1
  );
  return counterObj;
}
console.log(countNumbers('erer384jj4444666888jfd123'));
console.log(countNumbers('jdjjka000466588kkkfs662555'));
```

Comment: An alternative approach could be using a RegExp to extract all digits from the string and then count them (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/9h0wbLua/) although I am not sure whether it would be a better, worse or equal one, in terms of performance.